# Create new containers and move inside others

Tags: magento2, create, containers

How do I create a new container referencing a parent container and move inside other containers. What I try

```
 <referenceContainer name="content">
        <container name="product.container" as="productContainer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-container">
        </container>
</referenceContainer>
<move name="product.info.main" destination="product.container" />
<move name="product.info.media" destination="product.container" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong display inside move,

plz try,

```
 <move element="product.info.main" destination="product.container"/>
```

use `element` instead of `name` in move tag.

Comment: thanks I already made but I do not have any containers now on the specified area

Comment: sorry cleaning the cache seems to bring back but now I have the container under the tab

Comment: you can use as alias inside move tag, use of as inside move An alias name that serves as identifier in the scope of the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch in syntax please correct it by replacing **name** attribute to **element** like below.

```
<move element="product.info.main" destination="product.container" />
<move element="product.info.media" destination="product.container" />
```