# Creating a new container and placing it where I want in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, containers

I've search for some answers to this but I can't seem to find anything.

I understand how to create the container and then move the blocks in there (which I've done), so [this article](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111528/create-new-containers-and-move-inside-others) wasn't that helpful.

And I understand where I'm supposed to place up update code, so [this one](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180810/where-should-i-place-my-block-container-and-layout-files-in-magento-2) wasn't that helpful either.

**My question is more about how to choose a placement for my new container.**

Currently on my single product page, my related products are showing to the left of everything, instead of the bottom where I'd like it.

[image]

I've gone into

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout
```

and found the layout file that I could then try to create the new container under. However I find pages in Magento 2 are laid out weird and there is no easy way to place a full width area under the content container. Unless I'm missing something?

In `myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` I have this:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.details.info.panel" as="block-wrapper-to-style-details-related" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-content-details-related-container" after="content.aside"/>
        </referenceContainer> 

        <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="product.details.info.panel" after=""/>
```

I've thrown in that `after="content.aside"` in hopes it would move it down but it won't. It just hangs out there at the top.

Can anyone help me add my new container ***after*** the content container and before the footer?

Any help is appreciated.

***UPDATE 1***

Thanks for the help Ben & Quisse!

Below is the catalog_product_view.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="mage/gallery/gallery.css"/>
    </head>
    <update handle="catalog_product_opengraph" />
    <update handle="page_calendar"/>
    <body>
        <attribute name="itemtype" value="http://schema.org/Product" />
        <attribute name="itemscope" value="itemscope"/>
        <referenceBlock name="head.components">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="checkout_page_head_components" template="Magento_Catalog::js/components.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product</argument>
                <argument name="add_base_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="name"</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.info.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-main" before="-">
                <container name="product.info.price" label="Product info auxiliary container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-price" after="product.info.review">
                    <container name="product.info.stock.sku" label="Product auxiliary info" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-stock-sku">
                        <container name="product.info.type" before="-"/>
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.sku" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.type">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSku</argument>
                                <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                                <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
                                <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="sku"</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                    </container>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.review" template="product/view/review.phtml" after="product.info.stock.sku" />
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.final" after="product.info.sku">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                            <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
                            <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </container>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.tier" after="product.info.price">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                        <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">tier_price</argument>
                        <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <container name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" label="Alert Urls" after="product.price.tier"/>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info" template="product/view/form.phtml" after="alert.urls">
                    <container name="product.info.form.content" as="product_info_form_content">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                    </container>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.info.form.options" as="options_container">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="product/view/options/wrapper.phtml">
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="product/view/options.phtml">
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" as="default" template="product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" as="text" template="product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" as="file" template="product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" as="select" template="product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" as="date" template="product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
                            </block>
                            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="Magento_Theme::js/calendar.phtml"/>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml">
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <container name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" label="Product View Extra Hint">
                    <container name="product.info.social" label="Product social links container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-social-links" after="product.info.overview">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="product/view/addto.phtml">
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AddTo\Compare" name="view.addto.compare" after="view.addto.wishlist"
                                   template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto/compare.phtml" />
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.mailto" template="product/view/mailto.phtml"/>
                    </container>
                </container>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.overview" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="product.info.extrahint">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getShortDescription</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">short_description</argument>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">overview</argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Overview</argument>
                        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="description"</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
            <container name="product.info.media" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product media" after="product.info.main">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.image" template="product/view/gallery.phtml"/>
            </container>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="compareProductLink" xsi:type="string">.action.tocompare</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content.aside">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" name="catalog.product.related" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">related</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="related.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="related.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell" name="product.info.upsell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">upsell</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="upsell.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="upsell.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons\InCatalog" name="addtocart.shortcut.buttons"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons\InCatalog" name="addtocart.shortcut.buttons.additional"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

You are mostly probably wanting to see this part though?

```
<referenceContainer name="content.aside">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" name="catalog.product.related" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">related</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="related.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="related.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell" name="product.info.upsell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">upsell</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="upsell.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="upsell.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data"/>
        </referenceContainer>
```

I've already moved my block around I want, just trying to see how to get my new container product.details.info.panel to the content.bottom area (instead of a footer area unless that's my only option?)

Then if that is my only option I'll have to create my own template for this as Ben says to then have it layout the way I'd like?

***UPDATE #2***

This sounds like it should be an easy thing to figure out but it's quite difficult..

So as both Ben & Quisse have suggested I have placed `<move element="catalog.product.related" destination="content" after="-"/>` in my child theme default.xml

[image]

It's either ignoring that move command completely or this is the after content area in my theme??

Then, upon Quisse's previous suggestion I update that move command with `<move element="catalog.product.related" destination="page.bottom.container" after="-"/>`

[image]

Which then it ends up at the bottom of the page like I want, but it ends up in the footer where I need it to be in the content bottom area (within the content container indicated by the dashed blue line). I can't just put all my elements that I want under my description in my footer. There has to be a way to place this block in the bottom of the content container..

To answer Ben's confusion, I'm looking at the vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\layout\defualt.xml to see the main theme layout and the containers I can call.

Here is a little snippet I've been looking at

```
<referenceContainer name="main">
            <container name="content.top" label="Main Content Top"/>
            <container name="content" label="Main Content Area"/>
            <container name="content.aside" label="Main Content Aside"/>
            <container name="content.bottom" label="Main Content Bottom"/>
        </referenceContainer>
```

I would assume that I could reference the `content.bottom` container and place my related products in there but it looks like that is not the case.

I've played with it a bit and now it's getting there. I've updated the move command to be `<move element="catalog.product.related" destination="main.content" after="-"/>`

[image]

It now shows up in my #maincontent like I would like but not in the content container (indicated by the dashed blue line), how might I be able to get it in there?

***UPDATE 3***

So I've just made a template in my Magento_Theme and linked it exactly as you have and it's STILL showing up at the top. No matter what I do. I completely deleted all the includes in the styles.scss file so there were no styles either.

[image]

So I'm not really sure what I can do at this point..

Thanks guys!

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post your catalog_product_view.xml here

Comment: maybe try using `before` with footer? :)

Comment: @kia4567 I'm still not entirely sure what you're after sorry, I can't find any instance of a block/container named `content.bottom `. If you want it to display at the bottom of `content` you could try adding/moving your block to `content` and use `after="-"`. What happens if you try this - `<move element="catalog.product.related" destination="content" after="-"/>`

Comment: I've tried that but the related products just show up at the top for some reason.. I've updated my answer so look for UPDATED #2 and that will go through the most recent things I've tried and done. Thanks for your help on this!

Answer (score 3):

Like Quisse said it's hard to give an accurate answer without knowing the full details, but this may help:

`after` and `before` only work when the block you're moving/declaring and the block you're positioning it before/after share **the same parent**.

For example if you have this structure:

- Block A
- - Block B
- - Block C
- Block D
- - Block E

If you tried to set block E after block B nothing would happen as they don't share the same parent. But if you tried to set block C to display before block B it would work.

The exception for this is when blocks are rendered via `getChildHtml()` in a template file, in which case you can only move it by changing the template.

Also, you need to add a hyphen if you want to display it before/after everything. `after="-"` and `before="-"`

### Update

**Adding**

I have added a block to `content.bottom` and it works as expected:

```
<referenceContainer name="content.bottom">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test" template="Magento_Theme::test.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

[image]

**Moving**

I've also tried moving my custom related products to `content.bottom` and this works fine:

```
<move element="catalog.product.related.tab" destination="content.bottom" after="-" />
```

[image]

It doesn't appear to be an XML issue, could it be a CSS issue?

Comment: Thanks for your help with this Ben! I've done what Quisse suggested but worried as it put it in the page bottom and doesn't keep it at all in the main content section (so less semantic?) See my updated question with the screenshot of how it looks when I put it in the page.bottom.container now and the the catalog_product_view.mxl file. Also, in your answer your strictly moving blocks around where as I want to move a block called catalog.product.related out from the content.aside container and move it into a completely different container that I've created, which totally works.

Comment: I can even move that container around, but not to the content.bottom (which I see in vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\layout\default.xml).

Comment: @kia4567 I have added na update to my answer

Comment: I've updated my question with  3rd update but I'm not really sure it'll do anything for me. I'm not sure how else I can figure this problem out.

Comment: Damn it, it looks like the layout structure has changed elsewhere. Maybe a module or theme. Without having the full codebase I can't really help other than to suggest creating a new container that displays above the footer and to use that.

Comment: Well, thanks for all your help and suggestions. Much appreciated. I've given you the +50. Although we didn't get it answered we able to see what I might be able to work on in the future. Hopefully I can do some more debugging, figure it out and come back and answer this!

Comment: Please do, someone else will probably run into the same issue. Are you using a downloaded theme btw or is it custom built?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this comment until now. I'm using a Template Monster theme to learn and see the features I can play with. I also have a custom one I was setting up before we got that one so once I start playing with my Magento themes again in late Jan/early Feb I'll play with some ideas and see if I can update my findings here.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your layout structure (catalog_product_view xml's) solving this issue can be hard. But i'll give it a try. Have you tried placing it in the `page.bottom.container` or the `page.bottom` containers?

An even better solution will be adding your block to the `content` container and position it `after="-"` (add this to your xml tag)

[see before and after in layout](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_xml-instrux_before-after)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Quisse. I thought I had done that but hadn't yet. It does place it in the bottom of the page kind of like I'd like but removes it completely from the main content container element. Is there a way to have it at the bottom of the content area? See my updated question with the screenshot of how it looks now and the the catalog_product_view.mxl file.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I've tried that but the related products just show up at the top for some reason.. I've updated my answer so look for UPDATED #2 and that will go through the most recent things I've tried and done. Thanks for your help on this!

Comment: Have you tried reading the system.log for any errors or notices? Perhaps you've got an other error in your layout.xml which prevents the move from being applied. What you also can do is use [commercebug](https://store.pulsestorm.net/products/commerce-bug-3). This plugin can generate the computed layout in an image so you can visually debug your layout issue.

Comment: Where might I find the system.log? I've not heard of that before.

Comment: In your `/var/log` directory. All your logs should be stored there.

Comment: I don't know where that is? Is it in my child theme or vendor/magento?

Comment: It's in your root magento directory